# Changing size of greek in mathmode with Times fonts

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontsize, times

I'm using mathptmx to write a paper for a conference that wants Times.  Everything seems to be working ok, except for the size of the greek letters in mathmode.  The greek letters have a larger x-height than the normal text font.  Is there a way to adjust the font size of the greek letters to get a closer match?

For example, the following document shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
  x$\epsilon$x$\sigma$x
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider getting the Times fonts by using `\usepackage{txfonts}` or `\usepackage{txfontsb}` instead--those packages don't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, frabjous.  I tried txfonts and it looks much better.  I guess I'll be switching to txfonts in the future.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'm editing the question, so that my answer is more of a clearcut answer to it.