# Math and Times font

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am trying to use the Times font for normal text and variables, and the default math font (CMR) for math. I tried using the Times package. This partially solves the problem. But I want the text in math (by which I mean English alphabet and numbers other than greek, operators etc) to be in the Times font. How do I do this? Any comments or suggestion is appreciated.

For further clarity see this:

[image: Times math example]

EDIT: There seems to be a commercial font used by many journals called MathTime. Maybe this is the one that I saw.

Comment: According to the attached picture you don *not* want CM in math mode. The second equation is typeset with CM. That contradicts your descriptions in your question.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig: I do want CM in math mode! But only for greek symbols, operators etc. I have updated the image now.

Comment: Math Time uses Times for all the math, even the greek, as it should (mixing Computer Modern and Times is not a good idea as they are very different in both weight and style). You can download the free "Lite" version of Math Time on PCTeX's website if you want to try it: http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html#MTPro2_Lite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a LaTeX style file for doing exactly the same thing. It replaces all the greek symbols, operators etc. with CMR font giving you a mixed Times+CMR font style. The package is at:

http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~alexey/emulateapj/apjfonts.sty

Comment: Not working for bold fonts. All bold faces of English letters don't work, at least.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) package which supersedes [`times`](http://ctan.org/pkg/times) and provides math support for Times.

```
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Alternatively, try [`txfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) for Times in maths. Perhaps have a look at [this contribution by frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/changing-size-of-greek-in-mathmode-with-times-fonts).

```
 \usepackage{txfonts}
```

Comment: mathptmx and txfonts package doesn't seem to do the job. It renders both math and normal text in Times. And greek in Times looks ugly!

Comment: Mixing two different serif fonts in math seems a bit strange to me. But you could use `\text` of amsmath or `\textrm` and `\mathrm`.

Comment: yeah, it does seem strange, but it looks much more pleasing

Comment: Do take note that mathptmx and txfonts use different fonts for Greek, even though both use Times fonts for text and Latin letters in math.

Comment: Moreover, the Symbol PostScript font has some downright ugly glyphs, as commented and solved in [DoingLatexRight](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/DoingLatexRight/). It's better to use `mathastext` given by @StefanKottwitz

Answer (score 9):

Another solution: the very new package [`mathastext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext), released on CTAN today, allows to use the text font in math mode, i.e. for text, letters, variables. This would allow to use Times in math mode together with Greek and other math fonts.

Comment: Under XeLaTeX, this has proven the most effective solution for me. It was not installed on my system (I use primarily TeXShop on Mac OS X) and I was stunned to see how many new and updated packages were installed when I ran tlmgr.

Comment: This is great! A perfect and universal solution!

Answer (score 6):

You have to redefine the greek letters from the cmm font. It is simple because upper and lower greek letters are defined from 0..40 (decimal) in the cmmi font.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Letters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{13}
% [...] and the other greek letters
\begin{document}

\[ f(\alpha)=\beta \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to work nicely. But can I map the numbers and letters instead of greek? That would be easier I think.

Comment: yes, no problem. Depends to that what was defined before. For a letter you can make it easier with `\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{\`a}`. For the numbers you have to use a font with upright letters `{cmm}{m}{n}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in preamble):

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{gregasM}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{gregasM}{10}
\DeclareSymbolFont{gregasm}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{gregasm}{39}
```

For the same situation, this worked for me.

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's always better to post full examples. Please elaborate on your post